# Opensource LDAP C# (active directory)

Tags: c#, ldap, open-source

At work we use Active Directory.

> Active Directory (AD) is a directory service that Microsoft developed
>   for Windows domain networks. It is included in most Windows Server
>   operating systems as a set of processes and services. Initially,
>   Active Directory was only in charge of centralized domain management.
>   Starting with Windows Server 2008, however, Active Directory became an
>   umbrella title for a broad range of directory-based identity-related
>   services.([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory))

My first goal is to create a small lightweight windows forms application to search on *firstname* and *lastname*, using only parts of the name.

Context: I like some functionalities of this [tool](https://www.ldapsoft.com/exportdatafromactivedirectory.html). But it is not open source. And I need to make changes.
And since StackOverflow does not encourage reverse engineering, I would rather write my own software ;-)

Being a Microsoft .NET developer, I started looking for Microsoft .NET libraries: Which are they?
Is [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.aspx) it? Or is [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.protocols.aspx) it? I can't seem to find any really useful tutorials or easy to use API  documentation.

I have read this: [Using LDAP and Active Directory with C# 101](https://auth0.com/blog/using-ldap-with-c-sharp/)
Which shares [this](https://github.com/auth0-blog/blog-ldap-csharp-example/tree/master/LDAPClient). But that is basically nothing much.

Hence my question: **Do you know whether there is open source C# code available for download? Which supports connecting to active directory, and performing LDAP operations?**

Novell is a software company providing a similar but competitive directory, and they seem to provide excellent documentation about their ['LDAP Libraries for C sharp'](https://www.novell.com/developer/ndk/ldap_libraries_for_c_sharp.html) This got me wondering: 
**Could this be used to connect to 'Establish an LDAP Connection' and 'Perform LDAP Operations and Obtain Results' on Active Directory? Or should I just use Microsoft code?**
Considering AD is a directory services database, and [LDAP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367008(v=vs.85).aspx) (Lightweight Directory Access Protocol) is one of the protocols you can use to talk to it.
It should be possible right?

Please share your knowledge and experience with me. I am total n00b when it comes to AD. I promise: once you get me started, I will share my beautiful code with you all.

Comment: I made a small program before that query some information in AD. Let me find it. For a while start reading this document https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [this](https://github.com/EventStore/csharp-ldap) Novell based repository.

Comment: I have read some of the code. I bookmarked it for now. First I will try to keep it lightweight using only Microsoft libraries. This is less lightweight, but it does provide a nice and more complete API.